# /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found

Tags: shared-library

I'm building a program in a VM then deploying to another machine. This has been working for some time.

Today I've started receiving this error message when I attempt to execute my program:

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found

Both machines are running the same kernel version, and all packages are up to date:

```
$ uname -a
Linux darwin7 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:24:54 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

How might I investigate and repair this issue?

Comment: How is this a duplicate of a question that was asked _after_ it? Surely the other should be closed as a duplicate of this...

Comment: Age has never been a particularly important factor in deciding dupes. Visibility, quality of posts, etc. are. The other post has been viewed 6 times as often as this one in far less time.

Comment: @muru fair enough. Makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More lightweight solution is to **install just libstdc++** from *nondefault* repository:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.7-dev
```

Comment: I had the same issue recently (GLIBCXX_3.4.20 missing), but for me installing `libstdc++6-4.7-dev` was not enough, I also had to install the package `libstdc++6` (I don't know if it would work without installing `libstdc++6-4.7-dev` beforehand).

Answer (score 3):

In the end I realised I had different versions of gcc (g++) installed on the two machines. I was building with 4.8 and running where only 4.7 was available. Installing 4.8 on the target machine (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/306472/17164)) solved the problem.

There may be a more lightweight solution that doesn't involve installing the full compiler but rather just the required library.

Comment: Yes, In my case this is also the correct answer. I am running an HPC environment with several nodes. If you are in the same situation you can test the problem with this command: `for n in YOUR_NODE_NAME_ROOT_HERE{01..08}; do ssh $n "hostname; strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX"; done`