# GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found, how to fix this error?

Tags: ppa, gcc, libraries, shared-library

Whey I try to run the program **Layout Editor** (available on [this site](http://www.layouteditor.net/download.php5)) on Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit LTS I get the following output in the terminal:

```
$ layout
layout: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by layout)
```

I tried the command `strings` on `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` as following and here is the input and the output:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

How can I resolve this issue I somehow guess that it is related with `GCC` but cannot figure out how to fix the problem. Furthermore, I have tried a PPA as suggested on [How do I use the latest GCC on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04) and there is a similar question for an older version of Ubuntu at [GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164296/glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found). However, after I ran `sudo update` I get numerous warnings and the list I obtained with the strings command did not have new entries after installing `gcc 4.9`, so I purged the PPA([Toolchains Test Builds](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test)) with `ppa-purge`. Any help, suggestions on how to proceed are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found a solution already?

Comment: @StevenRoose I was able to solve the problem, after adding some backports and installing some software but I do not remember the details clearly when I remember them I will post them as an answer.

Comment: It seems that this is an effect of symbol linking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version You simply aren't linking to a library version recent enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX\_3.4.19' not found](http://askubuntu.com/questions/306467/usr-lib-i386-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-19-not-found)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I was having the same problem when trying to run other program, and found a solution on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605623/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-the-file-libstdc-so-6-0-15).

Basically, just do the following commands:
Firstly, install:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

This should already be installed by default, but try it anyway.
If it doesn't solve it, just do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I didn't perform the "dist-upgrade" command, but the ones before solved it for me

Comment: I think this was the solution I found after adding the repositories first, thanks for the answer.

Comment: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade solved my problem

Comment: problem solved without the need for `dist-upgrade` as `upgrade` proposed and updated my system with the latest `libstdc++`

Comment: repository addition, 'update'  and a 'dist-upgrade' were all needed on my end.

Comment: after the update you can check the latest version of GLIBCXX as `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04: In Nov. 2017, adding the 'untrusted, and unsupported' [ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) via add-`apt-repository` updated `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` up to and including GLIBCXX_3.4.24 -- and besides, this updates basicall ALL c/c++/fortran development tools on your machine

Comment: What if I'm not root? I'm on a user on a cluster that someone else set up and runs... so I can't use sudo apt-get or even just apt-get in the case of libdistc++.so.6...

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and Filezilla 3.32: same story, works after dist-upgrade.

Comment: Without adding that extra repository I only got up to 3.4.21 installed and an app I was installing required 3.4.22 With that repo I now have up to 3.4.25

Comment: "sudo apt-get install libstdc++6" and installing gcc-9 helped me. Thanks.

Comment: for my case, i have to execute "apt-get install software-properties-common" first

Comment: Solid answer, still working on Ubuntu 20.04.3. Cheers!

Comment: DONT FORGET to open a new terminal session after or your env will not be updated.

Answer (score 69):

It happened to me with anaconda 4.0.0 (as @mjp stated), but the fix for me was to run this command in my environment:

```
conda install libgcc
```

Comment: This solved it for me after trying many solutions from other threads.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04 as well

Comment: this really saved my butt a couple of times!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 - solved it for me.

Comment: this is much better.. worked for me.. was trying to 'import ROOT' in python

Comment: @yay this fixed it. I was just about to give up on getting openai gym running on ubuntu for windows

Comment: This will fix libgcc error when anaconda python in `echo $PATH` is ahead of default `/usr/bin`. Fixed for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Conda is great but so frustrating sometimes. Thank you for posting this solution.

Comment: In my case, I had to run this multiple times to upgrade to the latest version. Thanks for saving my day!

Comment: didn't work for me on ubuntu18.04

Answer (score 20):

I had this issue - it was because `Anaconda2` didn't have the GLIBCXX_3.4.20 version of whatever that thing is. Only up to .19, the same as yours.

**However, Ubuntu's library did have it**. So I just created a softlink/shortcut in the Anaconda library to the actual Linux library containing that GLIBCXX_3.4.20, replacing the previous one, and it worked fine after restarting the python GUI (Spyder).

There should be a folder called `libstdc++.so.6` in the Anaconda library, which is here: `~/anaconda2/lib`. Within this folder is the versions of the script/library-code-thing, excluding the one that you're missing: GLIBCXX_3.4.20

Follow these steps to solve the issue:

1. go to the right location and *backup* your current `anaconda2` shortcut (change its name so it isn't overwritten):

   ```
   cd ~/anaconda2/lib
   mv -vf libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old
   ```
2. create a new shortcut using the `ln` command (I am assuming that I am in the previous location ~/anaconda2/lib):

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ./libstdc++.so.6
   ```
3. restart spyder / other interface you use

It should now work!

Comment: for me it was enough to just rename the conda .so, then it found the os version without needing a link

Comment: Other solutions did not work. I think this is one of the ones with the least overhead and least invasive compared to others.

Answer (score 8):

I solved problem like this (but GLIBCXX_3.4.21) on CentOS but it is not dependent from os. The library is part of gcc compiler so need to install or compile appropriate version of gcc. This is table of versions of gcc and versions of appropriate libstdc++:

> ```
> GCC 4.9.0: libstdc++.so.6.0.20
> GCC 5.1.0: libstdc++.so.6.0.21
> GCC 6.1.0: libstdc++.so.6.0.22
> GCC 7.1.0: libstdc++.so.6.0.23
> GCC 7.2.0: libstdc++.so.6.0.24
> GCC 8.0.0: libstdc++.so.6.0.25
> ```

( full list of versions is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) )

It is not dependent from how to install gcc - it may be installed from package or compiled and installed from sources.

It is possible that system gcc libraries is available instead of newely installed. So need to specify environment variable where to find libraries for example in command line like this:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64 command args ...
```

Comment: I fixed this permanently by updating the link `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` to point to the newer version I had at `/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` with this command: `ln -fs /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`. The old version remains with no link pointing to it if you need to revert. A bit of a hack but it works.

Answer (score 3):

#### Before installing:

This workaround is required to avoid libstdc++ errors while running "extended" hugo with SASS support.

```
wget -q -O libstdc++6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --force-all -i libstdc++6
```

#### Installation:

```
wget -q -O hugo.deb https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.46/hugo_extended_0.46_Linux_64bit.deb
sudo dpkg -i hugo.deb
```

I found this solution [here on the Hugo support forum](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/solved-hugo-v44-extended-and-relocation-errors-on-travis/13029/4)

Answer (score 2):

I've had that numerous times through out the years with many different packages.  It has always been resolved by:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If your dist is upgradable, it will almost always bring down a new C++ library and reconfig things such as that they work again.   The issue is almost always caused by your system not pointing to the right library.  In my case, usually caused by pointing to a cross-compiler version of a library.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/YourGccVersionLibrary/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/bin/YourGccVersionLibrary/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.20 /usr/lib/x86_64_linux-gnu/
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about what this command is supposed to achieve. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Why `cp` and not `ln -s`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while installing Ubuntu 18.04 in Virtualbox with the live-server image. I'm not sure what I did wrong but got the same error

```
"apt-get: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: undefined symbol: , version GLIBCXX_3.4.11"
```

I was using 64-bit and had to download this file by using

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libstdc++6_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb
```

and installed using `dpkg -i`.
Then everything runs normal with APT.

Then did an `apt-get upgrade` to make sure all is well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (even for newer glibcxx such as GLIBCXX_3.4.29)

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

sudo apt upgrade libstdc++6