# PPA removed and purged but still showing available upgrades

Tags: apt, upgrade, ppa, gcc

This is on Ubuntu 14.04 (SERVER, so no GUI)

Ok so earlier today I was asked to upgrade GCC to GCC 4.9 (current available is GCC 4.8 for Trusty).

So [following these directions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error) I installed the PPA ubuntu-toolchain-r/test. Well, turned out we did not need GCC 4.9 and I wanted to revert back to 4.8. So I [followed these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) and I:

Used ppa-purge tool:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

I removed the repository with --remove

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

And manually removed the PPA file from /etc/apt/sources.list.d as well as the keyring.

But now, whenever I run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It's still asking me to upgrade GCC to 4.9 (and several other toolchain related packages.)

Comment: Just to clarify 2 thing:

1 this is a headless server. No GUI 

2 I do not want ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test to be involved in the server at all anymore. I want it and everything related to it to go away. I cant make it go away. Reboot didnt help

Comment: Just like pointed in how-can-ppas-be-removed " This is almost as logical as clicking a "Start" button in order to shutdown. –  Gauthier Sep 1 '14 at 20:49 " The accepted answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed the "click start button" commands line by line in the old answer I referenced. It didn't solve my issue.  I did these steps

Comment: Before you ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` did you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Yes, I did...and thank you, but I solved it by re-adding the PPA and packages and then re-removing them in the original steps taken. Some type of weird anomaly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove gpg key that I added using apt-key add -?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107177/how-can-i-remove-gpg-key-that-i-added-using-apt-key-add)

Answer (score 6):

All of what you did is just right. But you miss to do one important thing.

> ```
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
>
>
> sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
> ```
>
> And manually removed the PPA file from /etc/apt/sources.list.d as well
>   as the keyring.

Now before doing

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

you should make

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then make

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Your problem is you are still working on the software list that containing that repository, so you have to do `apt-get update` to update this list without the `ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` repository.

Comment: How to manually remove the keyring?

Answer (score -1):

The first command will only disable the PPA, not actually remove and install the original packages from Ubuntu repository:

> sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

So you'll need to enable the Repository one more time, go to Software Center  > Edit menu > Sources, and run ppa-purge first.

> sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

Comment: I'm Sorry, 2 things:
1 this is a headless server. No GUI
2 I do not want ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test to be involved in the server at all. I want it and everything related to it to go away.

Comment: I'm just pointing out the only thing you did was disable the repository, not actually "remove" it like the commang suggest or rollback to the packages from the official Ubuntu repository. If you did not install anything from this repository, did you run apt-get update before disabling it?

Comment: If you re-read my original question, I have done all of the steps in your answer.

Comment: you can see the output here from your answer 

http://hastebin.com/popevacipi.rb

Comment: and yes, I've run sudo apt-get update at every imaginable interval in this process

Comment: You couldn't find a package list because you disabled the repository, with apt-add-repository --remove, before purging it with ppa-purge.

Comment: Again, I ran ppa-purge first.