# Error running make to build Sage on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, compiling

I am attempting to compile Sage on Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded the binaries and installed a package. I run "make" in my Sage directory and this is what I get:

```
> [maxima-5.35.1.p2] Now installing the Maxima library as
> '/home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/ecl//maxima.fas'...
> [maxima-5.35.1.p2]  [maxima-5.35.1.p2] real   5m8.176s
> [maxima-5.35.1.p2] user   4m31.916s [maxima-5.35.1.p2] sys    0m20.496s
> [maxima-5.35.1.p2] Successfully installed maxima-5.35.1.p2
> [maxima-5.35.1.p2] Deleting temporary build directory
> [maxima-5.35.1.p2]
> /home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/var/tmp/sage/build/maxima-5.35.1.p2
> [maxima-5.35.1.p2] Finished installing maxima-5.35.1.p2.spkg cd ../..
> && sage-logger -p './sage --docbuild --no-pdf-links all html '
> logs/dochtml.log [dochtml]
> /home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/bin/python:
> /home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version
> `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by
> /home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/libbrial.so.0);
> 'sage_setup.docbuild' is a package and cannot be directly executed
> Makefile:1023: recipe for target 'doc-html' failed make[2]: ***
> [doc-html] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory
> '/home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/build/make' Makefile:846: recipe for
> target 'all' failed make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving
> directory '/home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/build/make'
> 
> real  110m50.466s user    102m18.460s sys 5m7.284s
> *************************************************************** Error building Sage.
>
```

> The following package(s) may have failed to build (not necessarily
>   during this run of 'make all'):
>
> The build directory may contain configuration files and other
>   potentially helpful information. WARNING: if you now run 'make' again,
>   the build directory will, by default, be deleted. Set the environment
>   variable SAGE_KEEP_BUILT_SPKGS to 'yes' to prevent this.
>
> Makefile:16: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 1

Following the suggestion in the error message, I changed my environmental variables as follows (I added the second line):

> ~/Desktop/SageMath$ cat /etc/environment
>   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
>   export SAGE_KEEP_BUILT_SPKGS=yes

Then, following a suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error) I executed the following:

> sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

When I run "make", I still get the following errors:

```
> [sagelib-7.3]  [sagelib-7.3] real 0m4.203s [sagelib-7.3] user 0m3.516s
> [sagelib-7.3] sys 0m0.460s cd ../.. && sage-logger -p './sage
> --docbuild --no-pdf-links all html ' logs/dochtml.log [dochtml] /home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/bin/python:
> /home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version
> `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by
> /home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/libbrial.so.0);
> 'sage_setup.docbuild' is a package and cannot be directly executed
> Makefile:1023: recipe for target 'doc-html' failed make[2]: ***
> [doc-html] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory
> '/home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/build/make' Makefile:846: recipe for
> target 'all' failed make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving
> directory '/home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/build/make'
> 
> real  0m6.692s user   0m5.536s sys    0m0.800s
> *************************************************************** Error building Sage.
> 
> The following package(s) may have failed to build (not necessarily
> during this run of 'make all'):
> 
> The build directory may contain configuration files and other
> potentially helpful information. WARNING: if you now run 'make' again,
> the build directory will, by default, be deleted. Set the environment
> variable SAGE_KEEP_BUILT_SPKGS to 'yes' to prevent this.
> 
> Makefile:16: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Can someone please advise? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us where you downloaded Sage. Most often a source tarball includes an executable script called `configure` or `autogen.sh` that needs to be run before `make` to set up the build environment. Did you do this? Or was there no such file?

Comment: Hi, Zanna. I downloaded it from sagemath.org. The readme file didn't say I needed to compile anything. In fact, I was able to execute sage. It was only after I downloaded and installed a package; and then ran "make" that I encountered a problem.

Yes, it came with a configure file. I just ran "make configure" and it said "make: 'configure' is up to date."

Comment: @user584936 And what is this package that you downloaded and installed?

Comment: Ah you don't `make configure` you run the configure script like this `./configure` do that and tell us your next problem... but what is the program you are trying to compile, if not Sage?

Comment: @Zanna : I ran `./configure` without any issue.

@edwinksl : The package I downloaded was `polytopes_db_4d` obtained via typing in a shell `./sage -i polytopes_db_4d`

Comment: I may have come up with a fix for this following [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/yAsyKA-pA4M) (cf. the second to last message) but may have also inadvertently created another issue that I hope you can still assist me with.

I ran `ldd /usr/bin/eog` and found `libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

Then I tried to create hard links to the new libstdc++ compiler; but accidentally removed the compiler with: `ulink libstdc++.so.6.0.20`! (Didn't know `ulink` is effectively `rm`)

Comment: Continuing, now I have

`~/Desktop/SageMath$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.22`

and

:~/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib$ ls *libstdc* -l

`libstdc++.a`
`libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.20`
`libstdc++.so.6.0.20-gdb.py`

So it seems like both

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`
`/home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/libstdc++.so`

are using `libstdc++.so.6.0.22` instead of `libstdc++.so.6`. The problem is that `libstdc++.so.6.0.22` doesn't seem to exist (can't find it using `locate`). Advise?

Comment: after `./configure` exits without errors (and you've thanked any applicable divine powers) then you run `make`, and usually it works OK. As far as I can tell there was no problem except that you didn't do that. Personally, I'm confused by your subsequent messages (`ulink`??) Can you please [edit] your question instead of putting additional info in comments.

Answer (score 2):

1. Verify your current libstdc++ has `GLIBCXX_3.4.21`:

   ```
   strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.21
   ```
2. Create a symlink as follows:

   ```
   ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21 /home/davidk/Desktop/SageMath/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6
   ```
3. `make`

Comment: I have the same error as the original post, on my fresh ubuntu 16.04. This solution fixed the error.