# failed to resolve /libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, compiling, gcc, compiler

Here is one question that encountered during the make process of

```
gcc4.6.2
```

as I tried to type the `make -j16` , there showed the following error messages:

I tried to search the web site by google and found that it might due to gcc version which will be compiled with older version so that it did not exist the `CXXABI_1.3.8`.I also tried to search the directory that the error message mentioned, that is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiccu.so.55` which is exist in my directory and I also tried to use `LIBRARY_PATH =/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$LIBRARY_PATH` and `export LIBRARY_PATH`  then remake the gcc. but it still show the following message. I do not know exactly how to fix this problem ? 
How to get a newer version of libstdc++ ?

Thanks you!

PS: My os is Ubuntu16.04 LTS 64 bit.

```
/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
make[4]: *** [de.mo] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
msgfmt: /home/paultsai/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
make[4]: *** [fr.mo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/paultsai/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/po'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/paultsai/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/paultsai/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
make[1]: *** [all-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing gstdint.h commands
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/paultsai/gcc'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I think you need gcc-4.9 This [related post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu) and [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error) Should prove useful to you.