# MatLab does not open after Psychtoolbox - lib errors

Tags: software-installation, matlab, error-handling

I am using U14.04 and I have MatLab R2016b. I needed Psychtoolbox and I followed [the instructions on its website to install](http://psychtoolbox.org/download/). During installation, I was asked to change libraries. The message told it was necessary for Psychtoolbox. I accepted and then, I tried to open MatLab on terminal. I am adding the errors. I could not find even any other one having similar problem. I am searching and trying to find another way but meanwhile, I wanted to ask at least to help others.

If the situation changes, I will update this question. If you have any idea, I would be glad to hear.

```
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwi18n.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwi18n.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwcpp11compat.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libicuuc.so.56)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libicui18n.so.56)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libut.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libut.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwfl.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmlutil.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_log.so.1.56.0)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_regex.so.1.56.0)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_regex.so.1.56.0)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libboost_serialization.so.1.56.0)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwregexp.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmpath.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwsettingscore.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwsettingscore.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwopcmodel.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwopczippackage.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwopcmwservices.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwwebproxy.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libCppMicroServices.so.2.1.0)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflnetwork.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwflstoragevfs.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwstoragefileprovider.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwxmlcore.so)
```

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error