# mv: cannot open shared object file "libstdc++.so.6": too big nesting of symbolic links

Tags: command-line

The error might be a bit different than the one from the topic- I was translating it from my native language.

After everything failed, I tried doing as mjp pointed in this post:
[GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found, how to fix this error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error/764572#764572?newreg=6f406320332e4ec096927f4cd8621419)

But as a result every command- apt-get, mv, cp returns the error from the topic title. I cannot go back to the backup version of the file.

At the moment I can't even log into Ubuntu. I got lopped inside the login screen. Everytime I try to login, screen gets black and I get back to login. I can only use the comand via ctrl+alt+F3

What should I do?

Answer for steeldriver (please look at the comment):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Jun 17 21:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 979056 May 7 2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.19

lrwxrwrwx 1 root root 19 May 7 2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.old -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

Comment: What **exactly** did you do? (if you ran an `ln` command, what libraries did you link from and to?). You *may* be able to fix it by booting into the recovery root shell, remounting the filesystem in read-write mode, then using the statically-linked `busybox ln` to revert your snafu. In the meantime try `/bin/busybox ls -l /usr/lib/$(uname -m)-linux-gnu/libstdc++*` and add the result to your question

Comment: I cant' really paste because I'm working on alt+ctr+f3 shell, I'll re-write it in new post

Comment: @steeldriver The OP added the output of your command as an answer to their question - I placed it into the original question.  It *looks* like the op was in the wrong directory when they created a link to the library.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow revert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[I must admit I'm a bit puzzled why basic utilities like `mv` or `cp` would break because of `libstdc++.so.6`, however asssuming that's the reason, here's what I would try]*

Your `busybox ls` output indicates that you have managed to recursively link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` to itself. Thankfully, it appears that you have not deleted or overwritten the actual `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.19` library. So you should be able to recover by re-creating the symbolic link.

The gotcha will be if either `sudo` or `ln` or both rely on the `libstdc++` library. (Presumably `bash` doesn't, since you are able to login with a shell at the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> virtual terminal.)

If `sudo` is broken, then you should still be able to boot into a root shell from recovery mode, as described in [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell). You will then need to remount the root filesystem in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

After that, you can attempt to fix the broken link

```
ln -sf libstdc++.so.6.19 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

(this should create a *relative symlink* that is resolved relative to the target path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, similar to your `.old` link).

Assuming that fails because `ln` depends on `libstdc++.so`, you can try again using the statically-linked `busybox` executable, which has a built-in `ln`:

```
/bin/busybox ln -sf libstdc++.so.6.19 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

If that works, you can `exit` the root shell to proceed with the normal boot.

Comment: But the sudo command works fine. Sudo does not seem to rely on libstdc++. Should I still boot into root shell?

Comment: ln -sf libstdc++.so.6.19 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

results in the same error. 

/bin/busybox ln -sf libstdc++.so.6.19 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

 says: ln: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: File exists

Comment: @Kokos34 hmm... you definitely did `ln -sf` not just `ln -s`? will need to think about that

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Checked again. Maybe I should firstly delete the file? -f flag means "force" or "folder"?

Comment: Yes `-f` means force - by all means try deleting first (with `busybox rm` if necessary) - just make sure to delete the broken link (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6) not the real file (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.19). Alternatively, once you've deleted the broken link you could just use `busybox mv` to rename the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.old` link back to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: Thank you very much. After I've renamed the file to libstdc++ they problem was solved