# How do I fix apt-get? I can't install or update anything

Tags: apt

`sudo apt-get update`:

```
apt-get: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by apt-get)
apt-get: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by apt-get)
apt-get: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt-get: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt-get: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt-get: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)
apt-get: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)
apt-get: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)
```

This is not a fresh install. I also tried to fix it by reinstalling the libc6-udeb package.

`sudo dpkg  -i libc6-udeb_2.24-12_i386.udeb`:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc6-dbg:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstdc++-6-dev:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc6:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstdc++-4.8-dev:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc6-dev:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 245802 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libc6-udeb_2.24-12_i386.udeb ...
Unpacking libc6-udeb (2.24-12) ...
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess rm command for cleanup was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
Setting up libc6-udeb (2.24-12) ...
```

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` came back as:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this on a fresh install?  Have you done anything recently that could have caused this?

Comment: This resembles [GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found, how to fix this error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error) except that you are getting segfaults, even from programs that don't actually use C++ (the `rm` command, for example, is unlikely to call anything in Ubuntu C++ standard library implementation). Maybe more than libstdc++ is absent/broken. Were you running those commands inside a Python virtual environment (Anaconda or not)? Is this on a virtual server that was set up for you, an Ubuntu system you installed yourself, or something else?

Comment: it's not a virtual/cloud, it's a local machine that I installed some time ago. it was working until yesterday.

Comment: I actually started out with Ubuntu 12.10 and arrived at a point where updating was not possible because Canonical moved the repositories to an 'archive' area after service expired(ended up upgrading to 14.04 LTS). If you are running a version that is older, it would be worth looking into whether the repos have been moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes things go so horribly wrong that the only way to fix them is by starting over.
Thanks guys, but after trying everything else with no luck I knew i had to reinstall a new clean system and that's what i did. now everything works great.