# GLIBCXX 3.4.30 not found in conda environment

Tags: package-management, c++, pip, anaconda

I am installing a package with pip in my conda environment and I keep getting this error:

`` ImportError: /home/anavani/anaconda3/envs/dmcgb/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-13.so.1) ``

I looked on previous stack overflow posts and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error) and I followed what the top comment said to do and ran these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

When I run `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` to check the latest version of GLIBCXX, I get this output:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
```

so I'm not sure what's wrong as GLIBCXX_3.4.30 is installed.

Any help would be appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: I don't know about your particular situation, but the `strings` command you give is just finding alphanum strings in a library file; if you want to know if the system sees that library look at `ldd`. Also, your error relates to a file beneath your home folder but that strings command is operating on a file in /usr/lib.

Comment: I've added a comprehensive answer to a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77940023/859591

Answer (score 12):

I got a very similar issue, and solved it by linking the the lib file into the conda environment. For your situation you may try something like this:

```
ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /home/anavani/anaconda3/envs/dmcgb/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

Answer (score 2):

I also meet with the similar problem, with the answer by Jason, I use "ln" command to solve it. Because I already had the GLIBCXX_3.4.30 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6. Then link it with library used in cython. Scipy package usually appears this kind of problem.

```
ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 $HOME/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: This worked for v2.0.1 building from source: `ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got the similar problem:

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` not found (required by /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/<env_name>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

As can be seen in the error message, this error is due to `miniconda3`, so I added the following lib to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which works for me in some cases

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/<username>/miniconda3/lib`

But there might be a more convenient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, seems that installing cmake via conda does the trick.

```
conda install cmake
```

Comment: This made no difference for me, and I have no idea why it would.

Comment: Neither for me.